# How to store username and password details from my app to my database and how to connect my app with my database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, kotlin

I am trying to build an Android app but I stuck at my login page.
I don't know how to store a user's information into my database and how to match when the user tries to login again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the sqlite database tutorials to store the data into the database. If you are storing the data in the database that is in the server, then also see the tutorials on connecting to the server database using any volley or retrofit etc.

Always its better dont store password in the text format, hash it with the hashing algorithm like SHA256, MD5 etc and then store it.

In the sqlite tutorial you will get the method to retreive the data back from the database and from there once the login button is clicked match the hashes of the data and allow to login.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm